# Heat Equation: initial condition $\exp(-x^2)$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

$u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ given $u_0(x)=e^{-x^2}$

I know that I just need to follow the formula $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t}}u_0(y)dy $$

but I get to a point in the integration where I'm not sure how to proceed. 
$$\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{2xy-2y^2}dy$$

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you know square completion for gaussian integrals ? You can look it up here https://learnbayes.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=77:completesquare&catid=83&Itemid=479&showall=1&limitstart= , this should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

you have to complete the squares in the exponent

$$ 2xy-2y^2=-2(y^2-xy)=-2((y-\frac{x}{2})^2-\frac{x^2}{4})$$

Then use properties of exponensiation separete the exponent $\frac{x^2}{4}$ in order to take it outside the integral and proced to integrate only

$$ \int e^{-2(y-\frac{x}{2})^2 $$

which easier.

Comment: Sorry I'm still having trouble with the integration. I make a substitution $z=y - \frac{x}{2}$ and end up getting $K\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-1}{2t}z^2}dz$ where K is a constant which I am still unsure of how to solve